# Maven not downloading the dependencies of jar which is mentioned as a dependency

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have one maven dependency and which i mentioned in POM.xml of the project. The dependency jar dependent on few other jars. How can we make Maven download the chain of dependencies?

Where are Gradle downloads all the dependents for the jar.

Help will be greatly appriciated.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Comment: use *mvn clean install* to download dependencies.

Comment: Perhaps what you want to do is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: Agree with Soora. If the dependency you put in the pom is available in maven central repository. It should be downloaded after you run " mvn install "

Answer (score 1):

In order to download the dependencies, you can execute

> mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

After running it you will get all downloaded dependencies located under **target/dependency** folder

Comment: I don't think "copy-dependencies" will worked for this case, He just want to get the dependencies. not the copy

Copy-dependencies :  Goal that copies the project dependencies from the repository to a defined location